# Android: How to hide Seekbar progress?

Tags: android, progress, seekbar

The `Seekbars` got that blue progress indicator. In my case I just want to show a percentage progress in in a `TextView`, so I don't need it.

How can I hide the blue indicator for the `Seekbar` progress?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"` in the layout file

Comment: This hides both the underlying track as well as the progress. Is there a way to hide just the progress part?

Comment: Create 2 drawables for bar background and progress background. If you don't want to show progress view then just comment progress background and android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent" will do rest of the part for you

Answer (score 2):

just use

`android:progressTint="@android/color:transparent"`

it makes progress transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 drawables for bar background and progress background.

If you don't want to show progress view then just comment progress background syntax ( in the custom class file ) and

`android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"` will do rest of the part for you